# How to save dynamically generated value in post type?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I'm trying to use the count of the amount of people that register a post id to a table in the DB. I want to save this `COUNT` value to the post_meta so when I display the list of posts it can also show the amount of people "registered".

```
function get_custom_field($field_name){
    return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),$field_name,'true');

$attendee_number = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."mro_attendees WHERE event_id = ".$project_id);
$attendee_limit = get_custom_field('project_limit');
$attendee_status = $attendee_number . '/' . $attendee_limit;
```

I then take the value of `attendee_status` and use it in a `hidden` field which saves to the post meta and then call it as one of the values in a loop I create.

The issue is that it does not update this value if I change the limit on the page, it can not dynamically change in other words. It saves it as is when it loads on the post edit page. So when I load the page to create the post, there is no `COUNT` so its `0` entries and there is no limit so it's `NULL`. So the attendee_status variable will be `0/`

How do I create this X/Y limit status so that it updates when there is a new entry or when the limit custom field is updated?

Comment: `get_custom_field()` is **no** WordPress core function. Support for 3rd plugins is off topic. Also you are talking in riddles. I can't figure out what your setup really is and what happens. If you want, you can file an [edit], rephrase the description and make it more clear.

Comment: It's not a plugin, I just added that function to easily get custom field data.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I want to have a project limit status that is tied to each post id. But I don't know how to save them to the post id individual. It has the amount of people currently attending and the limit combined into one variable but I don't know how to create that value and tie it to each post id on the front end. I want it hidden on the front end and saved to the post meta so it can be retrieved. I can't do it from the edit menu because it will save the status without it being dynamic. It can't change from the admin edit pot page. So I can't save or set the value there.

Comment: Not as comment. As edit to your question please.